# List feed from Google Spreadsheet is missing rows

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to import some data from a google spreadsheet.
It is a simple list of items with a few columns.

It was working perfectly for a while but now its giving me trouble

I am using the XML/ATOM feed at https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/spreadsheetkey/worksheetkey/public/basic and processing the xml.

The last few rows in the spreadsheet just aren't in the feed.

The issue might lie in the fact that it is attached to a form and some of the data was inserted through the form and some was inserted by hand.

However some of the data from the form is in the feed an some of the manually entered data is also in the feed. But it just stops at row 35. None of the data after that row is in the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malformed rows are not served by the API, we had a similar issue in the past. An encoding problem on a row caused the rest of the spreadsheet to be inaccessible with the API.